# Twilio ring for 20 seconds and then voicemail without dialing a number is it possible?

Tags: twilio

I have a phone number that I want to ring as a regular phone number. However, this number does not have a live agent to answer it. I want the call to ring like a normal phone number for 20 seconds and then connect to a voicemail. I don't want to dial a particular phone number though.

Can this be accomplished? I was considering using a queue? Or is there a better to solve this?

In short:

Customer -> Dials Twilio Number

Customer Hears ringing for 20 seconds   (we don't dial any phone number though). I specifically want the customer to hear a regular ringtone.

Customer hits voicemail

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a Twilio [Pause Verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/pause) (as the first Twiml Verb) to ring for 20 seconds and then after 20 seconds, use the [Say](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say)/[Play](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play) verb and [Record](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record) Verb for voicemail.

Comment: From the docs:  If <Pause> is the first verb in a TwiML document, Twilio will wait the specified number of seconds before picking up the call.